# How do I send emails through Outlook using R?

Tags: java, r

I'm trying to send myself an email through R, and I have an Outlook account (my email address ends in @hotmail.com).

```
library(mailR)

PASS <- as.character("XXXXXXXXXX")

sender <- "amalik34@hotmail.com"
recipients <- c("amalik34@hotmail.com")
send.mail(from = sender,
                   to = recipients,
                   subject="Subject of the email",
                   body = "Body of the email",
                   smtp = list(host.name = "smtp-mail.outlook.com", port = 25, user.name="amalik34", passwd=PASS, ssl=TRUE),
                   authenticate = TRUE,
                   send = TRUE)
```

Which returns this error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataHandler  at
> org.apache.commons.mail.Email.createMimeMessage(Email.java:1832)  at
> org.apache.commons.mail.Email.buildMimeMessage(Email.java:1268)   at
> org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1436)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)   at
> RJavaTools.invokeMethod(RJavaTools.java:386) Caused by:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException  at
> RJavaClassLoader.findClass(RJavaClassLoader.java:397)     at
> java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:586)   at
> java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)   ... 8
> more NULL Error: NoClassDefFoundError (Java):
> javax/activation/DataHandler

I have no idea what's causing this error or what I'm doing wrong. I see gmail users doing pretty much the exact same steps I'm trying and they don't have any problems.